# How to populate a dropdown list based on the choice i've made in another dropdown list?

Tags: drop-down-menu, powerbuilder

Hoe can i populate a dropdown list based on the value i've selected on another dropdown list?
For example: I have 2 drop-down lists. The first one contains OptionA and OptionB. If i choose OptionA, then the second drop-down list is populated with value1, value2, value3. If i choose OptionB in the first drop-down list, then the second one is populated with status1, status2, status3.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is in the "SelectionChanged" event of my ddlb_division object.  I have 2 DDLB's, ddlb_division & ddlb_section.

```
int li_division_id
int li_section_id
string ls_section

SetPointer(HourGlass!)

//Clears the DDLBs
ddlb_section.Reset()

//Gets the Division ID
li_division_id = integer(Left(this.Text(index), 2))

//Cursor to gather the Sections under the selected Division
declare section cursor for
select section_id, section_name
    from tadtp_sections
    where division_id = :li_division_id;

//Open cursor
open section;

//Get first row of data
fetch section into :li_section_id, :ls_section;

//Loop while we have rows
do while(SQLCA.SQLCode = 0) 

  //Adds item to DDLB
  ddlb_section.AddItem(string(li_section_id, "00") + "     " + Trim(ls_section))

  //Gets next row
  fetch section into :li_section_id, :ls_section;

loop

//Close cursor
close section;

//Enables controls
ddlb_section.Enabled = true
```